# COM object to interact with existing Save As and Open windows

Tags: com, autohotkey

Is it possible to use a COM object to interact with existing "Save As" and "Open" windows?

`Shell.Application` only lists the existing File Explorer windows, not the existing "Open" and "Save As" windows open in other applications such as Notepad++, as you can see by running the following commands:

```
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
ForEach ($Item in $Shell.windows()) {
    Write-Host $Item.LocationName
}
```

I'm looking to use this in AutoHotkey and this question is off of the back of https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/102127-navigating-explorer-directories/#entry634365

Comment: What are you going to save in explorer?

Comment: @DougMaurer Nothing in particular, I'm just trying to change the destination folder / directory in certain use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the class net like this :

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
$OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
$OpenFileDialog.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*"
$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() |  Out-Null

$OpenFileDialog.filename
```

Comment: Thanks for that but perhaps I should have been clearer. I'm trying to interact with existing Open / Save As windows, not create new ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`BrowseForFolder()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-browseforfolder) and there are several options you can apply to it. Here is a couple of examples.

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$shell.browseforfolder(0,"Pick a folder",20)

$shell.browseforfolder(0,"Your custom message",20,17)
```

You can even make it show files

```
$shell.browseforfolder(0,"Your custom message",16384,17)
```

Although it's only intended to choose folders, hence the name. It can also be a one liner. The following defaults to control panel

```
(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).browseforfolder(0,"Do something",16,3)
```

I'm not sure what you're intending to saveas from explorer directly. It seems that would be the function of an actual application, such as the one you mentioned, notepad++

Here are some useful links

http://wsh2.uw.hu/ch12f.html

http://www.lee-mac.com/directorydialog.html

You may also want to look at the capabilities of [`ShellExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-shellexecute)